# Cakephp baking models - prefix not added to associations

Tags: cakephp, model

I'm having an issue with baking cake models. I'm baking models as part of a plugin. I'm keeping the models dry by having all the logic in the PluginAppModel class. This allows me to change the schema regularly, based on changes to the application.

However, anytime I re-bake the models, in any associations I have, the className's are incorrect. For example, the default bake command outputs it as

```
    public $hasMany = array(
    'Item' => array(
        'className' => 'Item',
```

when it should be

```
    public $hasMany = array(
    'Item' => array(
        'className' => 'PluginName.Item',
```

ie. prefixed with the Plugin name. This is to ensure that I can port my Plugin around. Is there a flag I need to send to the bake command, to have this prepended? I can't see anything in the documentation. This is the command Im currently using

```
cake bake model PluginName.Item -c myconn -p PluginName
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

UPDATE--

Ok, this is a nasty hack, but it suffices for now. I overwrote the constructor class in my PluginAppModel as such:

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct(); 
    $this->append_plugin_name_to_classes();     
}

public function append_plugin_name_to_classes(){
    $associations = array('hasMany', 'belongsTo', 'hasOne', 'hasAndBelongsToMany');
    foreach($associations as &$a):
        if(!empty($this->{$a})):
            foreach($this->{$a} as &$b):
                if(isset($b['className'])):
                    $old = $b['className']; 
                    $b['className'] = PLUGIN_NAME . "." . $old;
                endif;
            endforeach;
        endif;
    endforeach;     
}
```

In the above PLUGIN_NAME is set as a constant in bootstrap.php. Im pretty sure this is not the MVC way of doing it, but it gets me out of a hole for now. I hope it helps.

Comment: That is a known issue I already reported back in the day - https://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/1781-plugin-information-gets-lost-during-baking - hopefully someone finds the time to fix this in the near future, though. I also posted a workaround for 1.3. Maybe it just has to be ported and merged into the current 2.x head.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I'm now following that ticket, hopefully get's resolved. In the meantime, it's copy and paste!

Comment: You could also take the code fixes laid out in the ticket and create a patch with test cases :)

Comment: Would love to if I had more time! And slightly beyond my level of experience in CakePHP ;-)